# Clear propel cache (instance pool)

Tags: symfony, propel

I need to force reread data from DB within one php execution, using propel. I already have a bit hacky solution: call init%modelName% for corresponding classes, but want something better.

Is there any single call or service config option for that? Like killing whole instance pool.

About service: we use symfony2 and don't need cache only in one specific case, hence we can create even separate environment for that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can globally disable the instance pooling by calling: `Propel::disableInstancePooling()` (`Propel::enableInstancePooling()` is useful to enable the instance pooling).

Otherwise, you can rely on PEER classes which contain generated methods like `clearInstancePool()`, and `clearRelatedInstancePool()`.

Comment: Actually, my problem was in another place, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @william-durand is there a method like clearInstancePool() in propel 2 (now that the Peer classes have been eliminated?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update realated objects and found out `clear%modelName%` should be called.

`init%modelName%` deletes all entries and related entires could never be read. `clear[Related]InstancePool` don't help.

```
$foo = FooQuery->create()->findOne();
// meanwhile somebody else updated DB and Propel don't know about that:
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `foo_bars`, (`foo_id`, `bar_id`) VALUES (".$foo->getId().", 1)");
// here we need some magic to force Propel re-read relation table.
$foo->clearFooBars();
// now entries would be re-read
$foo->getFooBars();
```